Newbie question: Do you use the join function to combine your objects into a single model?
I have only been doing still images but want to start doing animations. My models are made of separate objects that I want to move as a single unit. Do people usually combine the objects using the join function? I tried that but some geometry got corrupted. Also, it looks like it messes up the UV mapping that the individual objects have.
I've download and have been looking at the Blender splash screen files they look like separate object, but I can't move anything. I can't figure out how that works.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

You have some modifiers on the mesh that is active. Apply them and then join all objects

The OP hasn't shared anything, how do you know they have active modifiers on their mesh?

More importantly it doesn't really addresses the actual question. Converting to comment

No, usually not. You may join meshes if they have the same modifiers, though. Some objects can't be joined, like lamps, hair curves.
If you have a character, you should use armature to drive the character. In this case, there are no differences if you have one or many separate objects. You will have one armature object that will drive all objects using armature modifier or parent to bone (Ctrl-P).
Example of character's hierarchy:

If you have a solid object, it is not necessary to join objects. To join objects in one mesh, you have to apply modifiers and convert all curves to mesh, that lose your ability to edit objects. To make all the parts move as one, you can designate one object as the parent of all the other parts. These other parts become its children, and any translation, rotation, or scale of the parent will also affect its children. To parent objects, select at least two objects (select the child objects first, and select the parent object last), and press Ctrl-P.
In some cases you want to have one object in the outliner and do not want to select child objects in the 3D view. In this case, you should use collection instantiation. This is simple - put the objects in a separate collection, and then drag it from the outliner to the viewport. There is an add-on that simplifies this task: https://extensions.blender.org/add-ons/quick-groups/

Having all meshes joined into one object also means overhead labor required to just make it function, but more importantly losing lots of flexibility: things like easy parts hiding, different subdiv levels for different parts, harder to swap items, destructive workflow, .... So unless you meet a situation where you can't do otherwise, you should leave your objects as they are.

Thank you very much for your informative explanation.
I modeled a guitar so it's a solid object and want to make it fly around a room so I think that parenting is the way to go. I think i'll try parenting. THANKS!!
